# How to delete attribute sets that are not being used

Tags: product, attribute-set

I would like to "prune" my attribute sets. That is - I would like to delete all attribute sets that have been setup, but that do not have any products in that attribute set.

Is there a way - some script that has been developed that will identify unused attribute sets? That is no products in the database that use those attribute sets?

Please advise.

Comment: can you share your script?

Answer (score 2):

Try below script

```
        $entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getEntityType();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType->getId());

        foreach ($collection as $attributeSet) {
            if($attributeSetId = $attributeSet->getId()) {

                /** @var $catalogProductsCollection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection */
                $catalogProductsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
                if (count($catalogProductsCollection) == 0 ) {
                    $attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($attributeSetId);
                    try {
                        $attributeSet->delete();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Note :** first backup your database after run script

Comment: How i can used this code in magento 2